# How to query a SOAP Service in Java

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I would like to connect and query Trip Advisor's SOAP service. I currently have a WSDL for the service, and have connected to it using SOAPUI. I have been doing a lot of research about SOAP, but still am not sure I fully understand what I need to code in order to query the service as I would like.

The service takes an input of a simple place-id(I Have a list of many place-ids that I would like to query) Then it returns with the SOAP reply, which I would like to save as a new file(named place-id.SOAPrequest).

I have been doing reading on AXIS2, how to generate API code using SOAPUI, and launching a SOAP service in Netbeans.

I am currently trying to launch a AXIS2 service on my server, and then I assume load into it the java code that SOAPUI generating for the wsdl. But I don't know how to do this or if this is even the correct approch to the problem. Any suggestions or advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this step by step [guide](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=806) to Generate Java Axis 2 WebService CLIENT/SERVER